# Swift Why prepare func does not work properly

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am new to Swift. In my tableview controller I performed segue, and i thought prepare in landing view controller would be called.

```
// tableview controller
AF.request(url, headers: headers).responseDecodable(of: ProductEach.self) { response in
   self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
   if response.value!.error_message == "invalid product id" {
      print("invalid product id")
   } else {
      // 
      // do bunch of things with the data I got before performing a segue
      // 
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GotoDetail", sender: self)
   }
}
```

```
// landing viewcontroller
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   guard let destinationVC = segue.destination as? TableViewController else { return }
   print("prepare called")
}
```

I can't see the *prepare called* in the debug console.
Could anyone can tell me the fault i made, please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try `print(segue.destination)` right before your `guard let` to test

Comment: I just did that, but nothing is shown in the console

Comment: So maybe your `prepare` function is never called

Comment: Then what should i do to make prepare func to be called?

Comment: Where is your `override func prepare(`? Inside `TableViewController`, or inside `DetailViewController`?

Comment: it is in DetailViewController, the landing view controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235527/discussion-between-noby-and-aheze).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `prepare` method is opposite. It should be inside the "from" (**not** "to") view controller, which is `TableViewController`, not `DetailViewController`. And also, you should be comparing `segue.destination` against `DetailViewController`, not `TableViewController`.

```
// inside TableViewController
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   guard let destinationVC = segue.destination as? DetailViewController else { return }
   print("prepare called")
}
```